Can Inductors be thought of as storing voltage?
When I was comparing the capacitor and the inductor, I thought that just like a capacitor stores charge, an inductor ‘stores’ potential/voltage. I tried browsing the net to find out why I was wrong I couldn’t find the reason behind why my statement was false.
I came to this conclusion after reading about behaviour of inductors in a circuit. Inductors try to obtain obtain same potential as that of the circuit around them. At t=0 they act as open circuit and t=infinity they act as a wire. So they try to achieve voltage/potential same as the circuit they are in right? So they store potential/voltage?
Inductors store energy in the magnetic field. Can someone explain what this exactly means? And also why my statement (Inductors store potential) is wrong?

Go to any article about the memristor and you will find a diagram that contains this idea.

Considering the potential difference across an inductor falls to zero at DC, I would immediately argue that it doesn't store voltage. By contrast, the current through it slowly rises to, and settles at some non-zero value, after which the inductor opposes change in that current. Surely therefore it "stores" current.

"Can Inductors be thought of as storing voltage?" Voltage is a potential difference, so "storing" it (and nothing else) would be useless - it's just a bit of information. So I can't see how thinking that way would be helpful. You don't say "capacitors store voltage" because that's not enough to make the capacitor useful. It doesn't make an inductor useful either. Not unless you want to have a form of memory.

It's well worth comparing and contrasting capacitors and inductors. Understanding of one can usually be parleyed into improved understanding of the other, with an exchange of voltage and current.
Both store energy. A capacitor stores energy in its electric field. An inductor stores energy in its magnetic field.
A capacitor stores charge as a linear function of applied voltage, \$Q = CV\$, where C is the capacitance in Farads. Charge Q, measured in Coulombs, can also be written as As, Ampere.seconds, integrated current. We have a rather nice conceptual model for charge, an excess of charge carriers, which in metals are electrons, so it's very easy to intuit how capacitors work. A higher dielectric constant in the medium between the capacitor plates increases the capacitance.
An inductor stores volt.seconds as a linear function of applied current, \$Vs = LI\$, where L is the inductance in Henrys. Unfortunately, the name/model for volt.seconds is flux, which few of us have an intuitive understanding of, so we usually rewrite the inductor equation as \$V = L\frac{dI}{dt}\$, just as the capacitor equation can be rewritten as \$I=C\frac{dV}{dt}\$. A higher permeability in the medium round the inductor wires increases the inductance.
Rewriting the first form of each equation to get the units of inductance and capacitance is quite informative, C = As/V, L = Vs/A. This shows us how inductance and capacitance together can define a frequency and an impedance. Their product is squared seconds, cancelling the A and V terms. Their ratio is squared impedance, cancelling the seconds.

+1 for the last paragraph. That's something I've just accepted from literature but never really appreciated until now.

To develop an intuitive understanding of these two dual elements, think of the inductor as a kind of inert "flywheel" that stores kinetic energy, and the capacitor as a kind of "reservoir" that stores potential energy.
So, when we exert pressure (voltage) on the "flywheel" (inductor), its motion (current) gradually begins to increase without bound, and when we start filling the reservoir (capacitor) with fluid (current), its pressure (voltage) gradually begins to increase without bound.
Thus, for large values of inductance and capacitance, the inductor and capacitor can be considered, respectively, as a current source and a voltage source that can power loads.
When charged from an input source, they oppose it using the same means - with a voltage, regardless of the fact that the inductor is a "current device" and the capacitor a "voltage device".
The only difference is that the coil's maximum voltage opposition occurs at the beginning, whereas the capacitor's maximum voltage opposition occurs at the end.
See also my answers to Inductor as insulator? and If capacitors are frequency-dependent resistors, then what are inductors?.

No, inductors store current, they transform magnetic energy into current and current into magnetic energy. They store energy in a magnetic field.
Capacitors "store" voltage in an electric field.

Close, but not quite: they store flux.
For an ideal capacitance, we have: \$ Q = VC \$.
For an ideal inductance, we have: \$ \Phi = IL \$.
\$\Phi\$ is flux, the integral of voltage over time.  In the sense that "storing" is integration, you're actually pretty close; but we would normally understand "store" to record a particular voltage (e.g. a sample-and-hold), not an accumulation over time.
(Or, if we contrived a circuit where a voltage pulse of fixed width is generated, and then held at zero otherwise, we could integrate that pulse and store a voltage; but you can see this is tricky, because there will be some tolerance on both the timing of the pulse, and how accurately we can hold the zero.)
If we leave the capacitor open-circuit, Q is conserved, and thus V is stored.  If we leave the inductor short-circuit, \$\Phi\$ is conserved, and thus I is stored.
Whether you consider flux or current (or charge or voltage) more fundamental, doesn't matter to the ideal case; thus, you see either one mentioned in the neighboring answers.

Considering the potential difference across an inductor falls to zero at DC, I would immediately argue that it doesn't store voltage. Perhaps you are confusing the voltage across an inductor with voltages elsewhere in its periphery.
By contrast, the current through an inductor slowly rises to, and settles at some non-zero value, after which the inductor opposes change in that current. Surely, therefore, it "stores" current.
A capacitor will have a current that eventually falls to zero, and a voltage across it that settles at some non-zero value. It's the capacitor that might be described as storing voltage, not the inductor.
However, strictly speaking, capacitors and inductors both store energy, but that energy is manifest electrically as a voltage across capacitors, and current through inductors.

While capacitors store electric charge and in doing so create a voltage (potential difference) across their plates, inductors work differently.
An inductor stores energy in the form of a magnetic field, not in the form of voltage or potential. When current flows through an inductor, a magnetic field is generated around it. The energy is stored in this magnetic field.
At t = 0 (when the circuit is just turned on), the inductor resists any sudden changes in current. At this moment, it "acts like" an open circuit, because it opposes the sudden attempt to start current flow. The voltage across the inductor can be large initially. Likewise, at t = infinity (after the current has stabilized), once the current has been flowing steadily for a long time, there is no change in current. When there’s no change in current, the voltage across the inductor becomes zero. In this state, it behaves like a wire or short circuit.

I had an instructor that explained it like this:

An inductor will generate whatever voltage it can to maintain a constant current

A capacitor will pull whatever current it can to maintain a constant voltage.


